# Find all paths and sum the length of each path in the graph

Tags: prolog

I have the following graph database:

```
edge(v1, v2, 3).
edge(v1, v3, 5).
edge(v1, v4, 13).
edge(v1, v6, 25).
edge(v1, v7, 5).
edge(v2, v7, 17).
edge(v3, v4, 15).
edge(v4, v2, 4).
edge(v4, v6, 2).
edge(v7, v6, 15).
```

And here is my code to understand the output as below:

```
path(A, B, [A, B], X) :- edge(A, B, X).
path(A, B, PathAB, Length) :-
    edge(A, C, X),
    path(C, B, PathCB, LengthCB),
    PathAB = [A | PathCB],
    Length is X + LengthCB.
find_paths(A, B) :-
    path(A, B, Path, Length),
    printPath(Path), nl,
    writef(' Total: %d', [Length]), nl,
    fail.
printPath([]).
printPath([X]) :- !, write(X).
printPath([X|T]) :- write(X), write(' -> '), printPath(T).
```

Desired results:

```
?-find_paths(v1, v4). 
v1 -> v3 : 5
v3 -> v4 : 15 
Total : 20 
v1 -> v4 : 13
Total : 13
```

I'm having trouble not showing the desired results.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To help you we need some additional information. 1) Which prolog are you using? 2) What have you tried so far? 3) Where are you stuck? (for example printing/ traversing/ where to start). Also please mind you will get more likely an answer when you show effort - people like to help solve issues but they do not like to do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like your program runs as desired, only the output is "broken". Alter the ouput predicate and you are fine, for example:

```
printPath([_]).
printPath([X,Y|T]) :-  
    edge(X,Y,V), 
    write(X), write(' -> '), write(Y), write(" : "), writeln(V),
    printPath([Y|T]).
```

Now instead if single nodes of your path always a pair of nodes is printed together with their weight. To get a the exact order of your example you will have to re-write the search routine.

Tested with SWISH (removed one `nl` as well, not using `writef/2`):

```
?- find_paths(v1, v4).
v1 -> v4 : 13
Total: 13
v1 -> v3 : 5
v3 -> v4 : 15
Total: 20
false.
```